# argument of type "char *" its incompatible with parameter of type "LPWSTR"

Tags: c++

```
char re[MAX_PATH];
string FP = string(re, GetModuleFileName(NULL, re, MAX_PATH));
```

> problem in "re," after "NULL,"

Comment: You could have simplified this even more by not introducing `std::string` into the picture.  A simple `GetModuleFileName(NULL, re, MAX_PATH);` would have reproduced the error.  Also, please show the complete error message -- I bet what you are showing is only a part of the error message.

Comment: guys i fixed the problem, i must write "GetModuleFileNameA"

Comment: Do you know why `GetModuleFileNameA` worked correctly?  Knowing what fixed it isn't enough until you know the fundamental reason why that error occurred.  If you're not aware of why that error occurred, you will come across the same error for many other Windows API functions.

Comment: See [Unicode in the Windows API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/unicode-in-the-windows-api)